# Azure Mobile app authentication

Tags: c#, .net, azure, authentication, uwp

I am using Azure App Service and I want to use Microsoft account to authenticate my users but after the user enter his credential and get  "You have successfully logged in to website",the dialog does not close and does not returns control to my UWP.

here is my code :

```
  LiveLoginResult result = await liveIdClient.LoginAsync(new[] "wl.basic" });

 if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
 {
session = result.Session;
var client = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
LiveOperationResult meResult = await client.GetAsync("me");

var provider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount;
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider, true);

}
```

if I remove the "true" from LoginAsync I got an exception says  :
invalid format of the authentication response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use Microsoft Account with the Live SDK for sign-in, if so, then `user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider, true);` is not right here.

In this scenario, we need to use the returned token to sign-in to your Mobile App backend:

```
MobileServiceUser loginResult = await App.MobileService
                .LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(result.Session.AuthenticationToken);
```

The `user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider);` method is for authentication withe the Active Directory Authentication Library, they are different.

You can refer to [Client-managed authentication](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library.md#client-flow).

Comment: this throw an exception of type MobileServiceInvalidOperationException

Comment: @MustafaSaeed，Did you try to replace the `var provider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount;
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider, true);` with  `MobileServiceUser loginResult = await App.MobileService
                .LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(result.Session.AuthenticationToken);`?

Comment: @MustafaSaeed, what's the message of this exception?

Comment: @ Grace Feng - MSFT The request could not be completed.  ('authenticationToken' field is required.)

Comment: @MustafaSaeed, This is for authentication use Microsoft Account with the Live SDK, I saw that you just want to use Microsoft account to authenticate, then can you please try `user = await App.MobileService
            .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);` as in this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/#add-authentication), don't use Live SDK, I mean, remove other code. This exception is more like a service problem to me.

Comment: @MustafaSaeed, I just saw that Live SDK used for Azure Mobile Service is now not avaiable in UWP app, I'm afraid you can only use the method in the document I provided in my last comment to sign in.

Comment: Yeah you are right !
user = await App.MobileService .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);

this line at first was not working but after I changed the
token store on the advanced settings in azure Authentication / Authorization 
it worked ! 
Thank you. I appreciate your support. -
@Grace Feng - MSFT